# Module Not Found 'hidden'

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hidden'
```

When I am  trying to add this library to my model I am getting 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hidden'' error.

[image]

```
import tweepy
import hidden
import sqlite3
from langdetect import detect

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-47c0c67320f5> in <module>
      1 import tweepy
----> 2 import hidden
      3 import sqlite3
      4 from langdetect import detect

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hidden'
```

Anyone can help me fast pls?

Comment: Have you tried installing this library?

Comment: yes i did but i am getting different error

Comment: try sharing that error then instead of this

Comment: When I am trying to install, i am getting this error:
 Collecting hidden ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hidden (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for hidden

Answer (score 0):

try running `pip install hidden` or if you have 2 versions of python and, thus, 2 versions of pip, you could end up having to run `pip3 install hidden` for python 3

Comment: When I am trying to install, i am getting this error

Collecting hidden
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hidden (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for hidden

Comment: i am using anaconda for python3 that's why when i am trying pip3 i am getting: 'pip3: command not found'. pip is same pip3 for me now.

Comment: @AhmetErdogan in your case the command will be conda install hidden